# Add link to multiple items dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I am using the following code to create breadcrumbs from an xml document:

```
var root = null;

$(document).ready( function(){

    $.get( "/_assets/xml/sitemap.xml", 
        function( data ) {
            root = data;
            var pathname = window.location.pathname;

            var local_url = "*[url=" + pathname + "]";

            var parentEls = $(root)
                .find(local_url)
                .parents();

            var mapped = $(parentEls).map(function () { 
                  return $(this).attr("name"); 
                    })
                .get()
                .reverse()
                .join(" / ");

            $("#breadcrumb").append("<p>" + mapped + "</p>");


        } );
} );
```

I have the breadcrumbs displaying perfectly, but now I need to dynamically add  tags to each element and assign it the url in the xml doc. Could I do this in the .map() function? Not sure if there are any nifty methods in the API that would help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as modifying that map function, just have it return an array containing the name and url of the link, for instance in the return of the map function:

```
return [$(this).attr("url"),$(this).attr("name")];
```

And then in your breadcrumb line:

```
$("#breadcrumb").append("<p><a href=\""+mapped[0]+"\">"+mapped[1]+"</a></p>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The only problem is that I don't want the number of items to be hard-coded in the .append statement. There may be three or four links in the breadcrumb depending where you are in the site. So I want the returned string to have taken care of that already.